# Type script out put files directory sturcutre

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have below project structure and after compiling I expect the js files to be as below:

Actual structure:

```
/ProtjectHome/
|
-tsconfig.json
-index.ts
-service.ts
    src/
    |
    -a.ts
    -b.ts
```

Expected structure:

```
/ProtjectHome/
|
-tsconfig.json
-index.js
-service.js
    lib/
    |
    -a.js
    -b.js
```

My tsconfig.json contents is below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "include": [
     "./src/**/*.ts",
     "./service.ts",
     "./index.ts"
  ]
}
```

But with above type script conifg currently I get the folder structure as below:

```
|
-tsconfig.json
lib/
    -index.js
    -service.js
        src/
            - a.js
            - b.js
```

Does any one has any suggestions to modify tsconfig json so that it generates out put files as in expected structure ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `compilerOptions` field of your tsconfig you're listing your output directory (`outDir`) as `lib`. This means that when you compile your TS to JS, it's going to put everything in the `lib` folder. If you want your compiled JS to end up in the same directory as your TS, you can simply remove the `outDir` field in your tsconfig, and it will compile to your project directory.

You can read more about tsconfig and compiler options here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html and here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: what I need is index.ts and service.ts to be in the same location and rest of the files i.e. everything inside src should be output to lib. So its a combination of both and I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. AFAIK, there's no way to achieve this. The reason is that your index and service ts files will be referencing files in the `src` directory, but when you compile, the compiled versions will need to reference files in the `lib` directory. Typescript does not yet support path transformations when compiling.